# Construct a context-free grammar for a given set of words

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, reference-request, formal-grammars, machine-learning

I have seen a few years back a nice and simple algorithm that, given a (finite) set of words in some alphabet, builds a context-free grammar for a language including these words and in some sense "natural" (e.g., the grammar doesn't produce all words in the alphabet). The algorithm is very simple,  it has something like 3--4 rules for grammar transformation attempted on each new word. Any help in finding it would be appreciated.

Comment: What you want to do is *learn* an (infinite?) language after having seen a finite sample, with or without (too much) overgeneralisation. That is a hard task. What have you read about this? (If you only want a grammar for exactly that finite set, the answer is trivial.)

Comment: So what you're looking for is a (simple) algorithm that performs **context-free grammatical inference (CFGI)**. You can try searching those keywords on google scholar or something else. A quick search returned [this review chapter](http://www.tesisenred.net/bitstream/handle/10803/6651/04_alquezarMancho_capitol3.pdf?sequence=4) from a Ph.D. thesis. Maybe you'll find what you're looking for in there, or at least pointers to steer your search.

Comment: Given $w_1,\ldots,w_n$, how about the grammar with the rules $S \to w_i$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That would be a simple way to build a grammar, but the grammar wouldn't be very *natural*, would it?

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. "Learning" and "inference" seem to be the right terms. To clarify, I am not interested in this topic in general, but just in this particular algorithm that I remember to be strikingly simple (in the striking contrast with the papers on grammatical inference). I thought it might be well-known, but maybe the algorithm is applicable only in some narrow case or has some other restriction. Sorry for being so vague, I'll try to remember more details.

Comment: @Khaur, it very much depends on your definition of "natural"...

Comment: Any further hints? In what sense was the grammar "natural"? Any special connection between the words? If they have _no_ overlaps, then the idea by @YuvalFilmus can't be beat, so there had to be some commonality.

Comment: @vonbrand It obviously does, hence my emphasis on the term: that was my way of hinting that it was ambiguous.

Comment: As mentioned below by @Pseudonym, the algorithm I was looking for is called "Sequitur" (http://sequitur.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be referring to [Sequitur](http://sequitur.info/).

**Edit** It has been suggested by other commenters that I leave more information for posterity. Fair point.

Sequitur is an algorithm by Craig Neville-Manning and Ian Witten (of *Managing Gigabytes* fame). It's linear time in the size of the input sequences (although so is the memory usage), and satisfies the twin properties of parsimony (no redundant rules are derived) and utility (every rule is useful).

However, it can't (IIRC) discover arbitrary nesting structure. So a prototypical expression grammar, where an expression can contain an expression, is too much for it. But it will discover word boundaries in English text, and repeat regions in DNA. It's also useful for finding dictionaries for data compression (which is one of Witten's major research interests).

Comment: Welcome to cs.stackexchange! It is generally advised to add some description/details in your answer instead of just a link - links could break. It would be nice if you could add some overview of what the algorithm does and how. That will substantially improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are also many algorithms for DFA inference: given a set of words, infer a "natural" regular language containing all of those words.  For instance, Angluin's L* is a classic algorithm in this space, but there are many others.

Of course, any regular language is also a context-free language, so this could be used for your purposes as well.  Some of the algorithms are beautiful as well as useful in practice.

For more on this topic, you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/15512918/781723 and the surrounding literature.